# Webbrowser get return value from javascript without interop

Tags: c#, javascript, html, parsing, interop

I am making a C# winforms application in which i am using a webbrowser control for web scraping. I need to access an array in the html source. One way i figured can be javascript but i am not sure how to get return value from javascript function without using interop(Invokescript). Is there any way to execute custom javascript functions without using interop?

At the moment i am trying something like this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:function foo(){alert(orderInformation[1]);}foo();");
```

I want the value in orderInformation[1] in a string variable.

Also is there any other way i can extract the value in orderInformation[1] apart from using javascript. A block of HTML code i am trying to parse is:

```
             <script>
                var orderInformation=new Array(12);
                orderInformation[0]='10789999';
                orderInformation[1]='14222319';
                orderInformation[2]='CDD';
                orderInformation[3]='';
                orderInformation[4]='';
                orderInformation[5]='true';
                orderInformation[6]='CDD';
                orderInformation[7]='SEND';
                orderInformation[8]='Ted';
                orderInformation[9]='VXW';
                orderInformation[10]='12';
                orderInformation[11]='RP';
                ordersMap['1400319'] = orderInformation;
             </script>

var url = new String("/OrderCo.do?task=AOrder&OrderId="+document.forms[0].OrderId.value);
window.open(url,"dispopup",properties);
```

All i want is to access orderInformation and using interop seems to be a overkill.

Can it be done using DOM?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download that page and parse the text between `<script>` tags. This way, you don't have to run Javascript and can simply use text processing to get the order details.

Comment: that is what i am doing at the moment but it is not very reliable since it a long html page and there are some variations sometimes in the html response. Can the same thing be done using DOM??